# Grafana : How to use JWT authentication?

Tags: jwt, grafana, grafana-api

I want to use JWT for Grafana login authentication, [Grafana docs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/jwt/) dictate some steps for the same but `[auth.jwt]` default is not provided in `sample.ini`, and can you clarify what it means by `header name that contains a token` in the step mentioned for [enabling JWT](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/jwt/#enable-jwt) ?

Comment: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/main/conf/defaults.ini#L520-L530

Answer (score 0):

This is the header providing a jwt payload from the proxy in front of grafana - in the case of IAP(https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/signed-headers-howto) for example: x-goog-iap-jwt-assertion. The contents of this header is validated by the use of either source speficied i jwk_set_url, jwk_set_file or key_file, after which the claims for example for username and email can be fetched. Examples on IAP for this also available in the url above:

```
   auth.jwt:
      enabled: true
      header_name: x-goog-iap-jwt-assertion
      username_claim: sub
      email_claim: email
      jwk_set_url: https://www.gstatic.com/iap/verify/public_key-jwk
```

Note however - auth.jwt currently "broken by design" as mentioned in:
[Authentication Grafana via JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68178380/authentication-grafana-via-jwt/69824330#69824330)